# Automorphisms of order 2 in finite groups with no elements of order $p^2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with no element of order $p^2$ for each prime $p$. Also, suppose that $\vert G\vert\neq p$, for each prime $p$. Does there always exist an automorphism $\phi$ of order 2 such that for at least one subgroup of $G$, say $H$, we have $\phi(H)\neq H$?

Update: What if we add the supposition that $G$ is not cyclic?

Comment: Have you got your hypotheses right? As it stands, $G$ could be cyclic.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I don't understand your comment. The answer to the question is no because $C_6$ is a counterexample.

Comment: More generally, if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes then  $C_{pq}$ yields a counterexample.

Comment: @DerekHolt ah, I misread your comment. You are correct, of course.

Comment: No. There exists plenty of non-cyclic $p$-groups of exponent $p$ whose automorphism group is a $p$-group as well (say, assuming that $p$ is larger than the nilpotency length, coming from a Lie algebra over the field with $p$ elements with unipotent automorphism group). [I leave this as a comment, since you will soon once again change the question to discard such examples.]

Comment: @YCor - Unless you posted an answer giving the cyclic counterexample which you subsequently deleted, I think the bracketed comment is unnecessarily ungenerous toward the OP. I understand your annoyance at the edit that moved the goalposts. But (a) the OP is a low-rep and thus probably inexperienced user so may not have a refined sense of the norms around this; (b) to my knowledge nobody has posted an *answer* so the update did not invalidate an actual answer, and (c) at least the OP (with the word "update") explicitly acknowledged the edit, so readers can see the history.

Comment: @benblumsmith have you been through the history of questions asked by the OP, their comments, and their edits?

Comment: @YCor - Fair point. (I had looked at the OP's profile but not edit history. Now I have.)

Comment: @YCor - Nonetheless, for *this question*, it's not clear to me that the OP had a better option, in response to Derek's first comment, than the edit to rule out the trivial counterexample. On some previous questions, he should have posted a new question. But here, that would have been overkill since this question doesn't have an answer yet.

Comment: @benblumsmith indeed, my criticism was also that it is quite systematic that the OP usually asks some question about groups for which there is a trivial counterexample (e.g., cyclic, etc). A minimal effort when asking a question is to discard trivial counterexamples (of course the meaning of "trivial" is flexible). In some past question, discarding the most obvious examples, after they were mentioned, was the first step of a list of edits (the second edit usually comes after a slightly less trivial counterexample, e.g. a group of order $p^4$).

Comment: I would also criticize the OPs questions in that they have no apparent context. They read like: suppose $G$ satisfies some strange collection of hypotheses, then does $G$ satisfy this apparently unrelated conclusion? In this question for example it is unclear how or why the group having no elements of order $p^2$ is related to the required conclusion. When I see a question like this, I am immediately $99\%$ sure that the answer is no, so it is a question of whether it is worth the effort to concoct a counterexample, which is of course made more difficult as the hypotheses are increased.

Comment: Dear all. I got the answers and they were all things I purposed. The question will be remained with no change. Thank you all for your concern.